# Extending the Jinja2 template engine to style entities and make them interactive

Tags: javascript, python, css, jinja2

Is it actually possible to extend the Jinja2 template engine so it has somewhat of the functionalities [Elm](http://elm-lang.org) offers? Would it be possible to avoid the CSS and JS being inline? Did someone already try something comparable?

What I was thinking about is that you could just add a `{{ go-to-top-button }}` to the template and the template engine takes care of everything and I don't have to write a line of CSS or JS; it just renders a button with `position:relative` that is positioned at the bottom right and makes the browser scroll to the top when it's clicked by the user.

A few hints at what to look at in particular and how to approach this task would be immensely helpful as my experience is limited.

Comment: I just found out about django-elm. Maybe that does what I want.

Comment: I decided to write my own solution for this.